# « Responsable » est-il singulier ou pluriel dans « Nous ne sommes pas responsable[s] de … » ?

Tags: grammaire, accord

Il semblerait que les sources sur le web ne sont pas toutes d'accord sur ce point.
Dans la phrase suivante, responsable doit-il être écrit singulier ou pluriel?

> Nous ne sommes pas responsables des erreurs de frappe.

Selon moi il serait au pluriel, puisque *nous* représente plusieurs personnes, mais dans ce cas-ci *nous* représente une entité/compagnie ce qui me rend incertain sur la façon de bien écrire *reponsables*.

Comment: Quelles sont tes sources ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si *nous* désigne une forme honorifique (telle "Nous Roi de France"),

> Nous ne sommes pas responsable de ce problème : ce n'est pas à nous de donner la réponse à ce problème.

... ou que la personne parle d'elle-même (je l'ai entendu chez certaines personnes âgées, c'est alors une forme d'humilité qui ne met pas *je, moi* en avant), ou dans les expressions :

> Nous voila donc bien mal parti !
>
> Nous voila arrivée !

*Nous* est ici un pronom, et non pas un sujet pluriel.

Si en revanche il s'agit d'un groupe où chacun peut commettre l'erreur mentionnée:

> Nous ne sommes pas responsables de ces erreurs : aucun de nous n'est la cause de ces erreurs.
> On pourrait lire : Nous ne sommes pas *les* responsables de ces erreurs.

En modifiant la personne du sujet et le nom litigieux :

> Elles ne sont pas garantes des objets déposés.

---

*Complément :*

*Responsable* peut être *adjectif*  :

> Nous sommes *adjectif* : un adjectif donne une qualité commune  à nous, le pluriel est loin d'être intuitif, même si la règle l'impose (hormis les rois et les modestes).

Nous est global, mais, 'nous sommes global' n'est apparemment pas correct, même si chaque être vivant est sur le même globe et *responsable* de son futur ; il y a donc une intention, un contexte où la grammaire semble avoir des limites ; il reste à l'expression poétique de suggérer ses solutions.

*Responsable* peut être *nom* :

> Nous sommes [des] *nom[s]* : nous indique une pluralité, donc différentes personnes singulières, dont on 'voit' plus facilement la multitude

Comment: Si un responsable parle au nom d'un groupe, l'accord est au pluriel. Il n'y a que le nous de majesté (encore en vigueur en Belgique ?) ou le nous de modestie (encore pratiqué par certains auteurs) qui s'accordent au singulier.

Comment: Lorsqu'il s'agit d'un nom, le choix de mettre le pluriel ou non dépend du sens voulu.

Comment: @Gilles j'ai supprimé la phrase litigieuse

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Pour le complément, je ne sais plus comment on ouvre un fil sur Cosette

Answer (score 1):

Qu'est-ce que vous diriez de la phrase ci-dessous où l'accord est clairement audible, dans les mêmes conditions ?

> Nous ne sommes pas original.
>
> Nous ne sommes pas originaux.

L'attribut du sujet s'accorde avec le sujet reste à savoir quels sont les traits d'accord du sujet en question.

En français, il y a [trois cas classiques de disparité](http://grammaire.reverso.net/4_2_22_nous_vous.shtml) entre l'accord verbal et l'accord des attributs pour les pronoms sujets :

- vous

  - 2PL pour les verbes
  - SG ou PL pour les attributs en fonction du vouvoiement
- on

  - 3SG pour les verbes
  - SG ou PL pour les attributs en fonction du référent
- nous

  - 1PL pour les verbes
  - SG ou PL pour les attributs en fonction du référent

Dans votre exemple, tout dépend effectivement du référent...

Comment: Ce genre d'intuition marche bien pour un locuteur natif, mais pas pour un apprenant. Il faudrait aussi donner la réponse.

Comment: Non, dans *responsable de*, le mot *responsable* est un nom, cette intuition n'est pas la bonne. La bonne intuition ce serait *Nous ne sommes pas marecha… de France*. Personnellement, je choisis *al*.

Answer (score 1):

Qu'on utilise le nom ou l'adjectif « responsable », de toutes façons on n'essaye pas, à mon avis, de rendre qu'il n'y a pas d'auteur de ces erreurs, ou que personne n'a la charge ou la capacité de corriger, ni généralement d'indiquer sur quelle personne ou groupe exactement reposerait une responsabilité à cet effet etc.; on veut plutôt indiquer une [*limitation de responsabilité*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18963139). Ce genre de mise en garde apparaît dans des politiques et documents de nature juridique, et c'est donc sans doute le sens en [*droit*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/responsable) de *responsable* qu'on tente de manier; on pense sans doute à :

> Nous ne sommes pas responsables des dommages qu'une personne
>   pourrait subir si elle tenait pour avérée l'information,
>   potentiellement erronée, présentée sur ce site, et s'y fiait pour
>   faire ou ne pas faire quelque chose. Toute modification du contenu, pour quelque raison que ce soit, se fera à notre entière discrétion, et sans préavis.

...davantage qu'à :

> — *Ton fiancé, je ne sais pas d'où elle sort, mais il est vilaine.*
>
> [ Boris Vian, *Elles se rendent pas compte*, 1950 ]

---

Je ne pense pas qu'on puisse dire d'un véhicule commercial, même s'il était doté de la personnalité juridique, qu'il parle de lui-même en utilisant le [*nous de modestie*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=modestie&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) comme le ferait une journaliste, par exemple, qui rédige une chronique et dit quelque chose comme « *Nous nous sommes limitée à tel sujet...* ». Le genre varierait selon le type (société, organisme) et donc l'accord; c'est peu convaincant. Tout autant que l'idée d'un PDG rédigeant un discours au « nous » en contexte d'affaires et qu'on doive faire l'accord d'attributs, d'adjectifs et de noms au singulier et avec son genre biologique (apparent).

L'entreprise ou la société sont des abstractions et ce sont traditionnellement les employés qui, dans le cadre de leurs fonctions, sont ceux par l'entremise de qui elle agit, s'exprime et offre ses produits et services au client. Et c'est le sens du [*nous de société*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1928) : il représente l'ensemble des personnes rattachés à l'entreprise ou l'organisme. Et dans ce cas, l'accord de l'*adjectif*, du *participe* ou du *nom* se fait en utilisant le **masculin pluriel** (*nous ne sommes pas responsables*).<sup>1</sup> On peut toujours dire « *notre entreprise/société n'est pas tenue* de ... » pour ne pas avoir à utiliser le masculin pluriel.

---

<sub>1. Plus généralement, il y a des [*syllepses grammaticales*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4097) qui sont obligatoires (surtout avec « nous/vous ») et d'autres qui sont facultatives (surtout avec « on »). La *société* n'est pas, tel que mentionné, un « être » seul qui utilise le pronom à la 1ère du pluriel, critère qui permettrait l'accord au singulier avec les pronoms « nous/vous ». L'accord est rigoureux avec le pronom « vous ». Le pronom indéfini « on » offre davantage de flexibilité (et de complexité). Souvent autrement on n'a pas de choix, et le contexte dicte le genre et le nombre. Il y a des questions reliées aux [*verbes pronominaux*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4222) et plusieurs autres enjeux. Voir au *LBU* les §§ 248, 438+, 653. 655+, 753, 754, entre autres.</sub>